# Show logo in axis without image - Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How it can be possible to display this logo on this graphical User Interface without using the functions of displaying images and without a jpg file, ... !!!

Download this GUI [here](http://www.ohio.edu/people/gu/fsolveGUI.zip).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:**

it could be that the logo has been manually added after the creation of the GUI and without using the `guide` that, instead, seems the tool, used to create the 
whole GUI.

**In details:**

To show an image in a GUI it is necessary to first add an `axes` in the GUI to
which then, to attach the image by using the `imshow` function.

In the case of a "logo", that is supposed to be diplayed as the GUI opens
and not to be modified during the execution of the GUI, a possibility could be to insert 
the following code:

```
imshow('my_logo_image.jpg')
```

in the GUI's `OpeningFcn` which is executes just before hweufhef is made visible.

Looking at the `.m` file of your GUI unfortunately this is not the case.

It is difficult to understand how the whole GUI and in particular the logo
have been built, nevertheless, some considerations can be made about the GUI.

Opening the GUI with the `guide` tool this is how it appears:

[image]

You can notice an axes in the lower left corner, this is the place in which 
the logo appears.

So far so good.

Now, double click on the `axes` to open the `Property Inspector`: you will
notice something strange: the `tag` property of the `axes` is empty.

This is strange, because, `guide` automatically define a default `Tag` property
for each item is added.

Now, **AFTER HAVING MADE A BACKUP COPY OF THE GUI**

- double click on any point of the GUI not containing any `uicontrol`, 
  this will open the `Property Inspector` for the `Figure`
- go to the `HandleVisibility` property and set it to `on`
- save the GUI
- close the `GUIDE` tool

Now run the GUI form the CommandWindow (fsolveGUI) and then, again in the 
CommandWindow run the following:

```
gui_handels=guidata(gcf)
```

The function `guidata` will return the `handels` of the object in the GUI.

This is the output:

```
gui_handels = 

    figure1: [1x1 Figure]
      edit1: [1x1 UIControl]
 Untitled_1: [1x1 Menu]
     text11: [1x1 UIControl]
 Untitled_2: [1x1 Menu]
       File: [1x1 Menu]
pushbutton1: [1x1 UIControl]
      edit3: [1x1 UIControl]
      text8: [1x1 UIControl]
      text7: [1x1 UIControl]
      text3: [1x1 UIControl]
      edit2: [1x1 UIControl]
      text1: [1x1 UIControl]
     copyto: [1x1 Menu]
  pastefrom: [1x1 Menu]
      mfile: [1x1 Menu]
openResults: [1x1 Menu]
SaveResults: [1x1 Menu]
 loadeqfile: [1x1 Menu]
     output: [1x1 Figure]
```

You will notice **something strange**:

- the GUI contains an axes
- its property `HandleVisibility` is `on` (you can check it using `guide`)
- nevertheless, it is not present in the list of the `handles` returned by `guidata`

You can get the `handle` of this misterious `axes` with this command:

```
logo_ax_handle=findobj(gcf,'type','axes')
```

now get access to the data plotted in the axes with this command

```
axes_data=logo_ax_handle.Children.CData;
```

you will get a `54x192x3 unit8` matrix that is, actually the Logo.

You can verify it as follows:

```
figure
axes
imshow(axes_data)
```

Considering all this strannge thisngs, a possible answer to your question
can be:

- the GUI has been created without the axes and with the figure's `HandleVisibilit` `on`
- an axes has been manually added to the GUI whithout using the `guide` tool
- an image, the Logo, has been added to the axes
- the GUI has been saved with the `savefig` function
- the GUI has been opened with `guide`
- the `HandleVisibility` properety of the figure has been set to `callback`

You can test this possibility as follows:

- with `guide`m, create a GUI with, for example, just a `pushbutton` and an `editbox`,
  just to have "something" inside
- set the `HandleVisibility` properety fo the `figure` to `on`
- save the GUI (in the below example I've call it `add_axes_manually`
  and close `guide`

Then run the following code, e. g. from a script (Change the name of the image)

```
add_axes_manually
guidata(gcf)
axes('unit','normalized','position',[0.08 0.4 0.3 0.3])
imshow('Jupiter_New_Horizons.jpg')
savefig('add_axes_manually.fig')
add_axes_manually
guidata(gcf)
```

From the output of the two calls to `guidata` you will notice that:

- the handle of the axes is not diplayd
- the GUI now contains a Logo (a picture)
- the Logo is embedded in the GUI so, apparently, there are neither a 
  `.jpeg` file nor code to insert the logo in the `.m` file

The fact that the GUI has been saved "outside" the `guide` tool seems supported
by the fact that when you open it, some equation are displayed, while they are
not present in the `.m` file of the GUI.

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: Thank you for your Help. It's well explained. Before posting my problem I find that strange axes Children (cdata), but I did not find a way to add it manually. It's very clever your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically [two ways to construct GUIs in MATLAB](https://nl.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gui.html):

1. With GUIDE
2. Programmatically

GUIDE allows you to create and position `uicontrol`s and other objects in a graphical way. When the GUI is then deployed, GUIDE generates functions for the `uicontrol` callbacks in an M-file, and a FIG file to contain all the data for all the `uicontrol`s and other graphics objects you may have included in the GUI. Use this for GUIs with simple lay-out and simple `uicontol` behavior (read: *most* GUIs you will ever create)

When doing things programmatically, you have to do everything yourself -- `uicontrol` positioning, callbacks, logo positioning and display, everything. There is no FIG file to help you (normally), only M files you wrote. Use this if you want/need absolute control over the `uicontrol` behaviors, multiple sub-GUIs, tabs, complex interactions between MATLAB and `uicontrol`s, and whatnot. Much harder to do, but it gives you absolute control.

The GUI you linked to is apparently created with GUIDE. The PNG/JPG/whatever is embedded in the FIG file.